# Structure replacement possible complex RegexReplace solution?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to run a VBScript that changes the structure of a CSV file. To keep it simple I'm only using 3 data fields but there is a lot more. In a production environment I will have a CSV file with hundreds of lines.

The problem is everything is in double quotes.  The end result can sometimes be no quotes or single quotes or sometimes a mix of all three.

I have absolutely no idea how I should approach this and was looking for some guidance.  This looks like a job for RegexReplace but because it's mixed I'm not sure how to start this.  After the file has been modified I have to right over top of the original file.

**CSV Example:**
"apple";"12";"xyz"
"somereallylongword";"7687";"theredfox"

**Pattern**
"%1";%2;'%3'

**Desired Result**
"apple";12;'xyz'
"somereallylongword";7687;'theredfox'

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to make a new pattern type.  In my example:
"%1" - I keep the original double quotes.
%2 - Remove the double quotes.
'%3' - Replace the double quotes with single quotes.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can see a distinction between all numbers and text mix, but not with quotes. Usually one sticks with double quotes to encapsulate delimiters (,) and/or to embed quotes that will need to be escaped `" this \"program\" is it"`

Comment: The second element `%2` is always a digit number ?

Comment: Sadly elements are not always a number. It can be anything.

Comment: @Cyberdrac Please check my update answer and tell me if this solved your issue or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV file using ADODB:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1

Dim objConnection
Dim objRecordset
Dim sCSVFolder
Dim sCSVFile
Dim sValue

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sCSVFolder = "C:\CSV_Folder\"
sCSVFile = "your_csv_file.csv"

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & sCSVFolder & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & sCSVFile, _
          objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    ' Modify and write fields to new text file here
    sValue = objRecordset.Fields.Item("FieldName")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

This way you let ADO handle reading the data and removing the double-quotes and you can manipulate the data easily as a Recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try for this code by replacing the path of your CSV file and tell me how it works on your side ?

```
Option Explicit
Dim Data
Call ForceCScriptExecution()
Data = ReadFile("C:\Test\Test.csv")
wscript.echo "Before Replacing"
wscript.echo String(50,"-")
wscript.echo Data
wscript.echo String(50,"-")
wscript.echo "After Replacing"
wscript.echo String(50,"-")
wscript.echo Search_Replace(Data)
wscript.echo String(50,"-")
wscript.sleep 20000
'-----------------------------------------------
Function Search_Replace(Data)
    Dim oRegExp,strPattern1,strPattern2
    Dim strReplace1,strReplace2,strResult1,strResult2
    strPattern1 = ";(\x22)(\S+\w+)(\x22);"
    strReplace1 = ";$2;"
    strPattern2 = "[;]\x22([^\x22]+)\x22"
    strReplace2 = ";'$1'"
    Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    oRegExp.Global = True 
    oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern1
    strResult1 = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace1)
    oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern2
    strResult2 = oRegExp.Replace(strResult1,strReplace2)
    Search_Replace = strResult2
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------
Function ReadFile(path)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFSO,objFile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path,ForReading)
    ReadFile = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
End Function
'----------------------------------------------
Sub ForceCScriptExecution()
    Dim Arg, Str, cmd, Title
    Title = "Search and Replace using RegExp by Hackoo 2019"
    cmd = "CMD /C Title " & Title &" & color 0A & Mode 80,30 & "
    If Not LCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\cscript.exe" Then
        For Each Arg In WScript.Arguments
            If InStr( Arg, " " ) Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
            Str = Str & " " & Arg
        Next
        CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).Run _
        cmd & "cscript //nologo """ & _
        WScript.ScriptFullName & _
        """ " & Str
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------
```

***Edit : Batch Script Code***

You can do it easily with a batch script without using Regex :

```bat
@echo off
Title Edit CSV File
Set "Input_CSV_File=C:\Test\Test.csv"
Set "OutPut_CSV_File=C:\Test\OutPut_Test.csv"
If Exist "%OutPut_CSV_File%" Del "%OutPut_CSV_File%"
@for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%a in ('Type "%Input_CSV_File%"') Do (
    echo "%%~a";%%~b;'%%~c' 
    echo "%%~a";%%~b;'%%~c'>>"%OutPut_CSV_File%"
)
TimeOut /T 5 /NoBreak>nul
If Exist "%OutPut_CSV_File%" Notepad "%OutPut_CSV_File%" & Exit
```